# Why does the compiler invoke the -> operator twice

Tags: c++

The following code is extracted from: https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/Synchronized.h

I recent had a look at the Folly library, and found something interesting. Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Lock {
    void lock() {
        std::cout << "Locking" << std::endl;
    }
    void unlock() {
        std::cout << "Unlocking" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class T, class Mutex = Lock >
struct Synchronized {
    struct LockedPtr {
        explicit LockedPtr(Synchronized* parent) : p(parent) {
            p->m.lock();
        }

        ~LockedPtr() {
            p->m.unlock();
        }

        T* operator->() {
            std::cout << "second" << std::endl;
            return &p->t;
        }

    private:
        Synchronized* p;
    };

    LockedPtr operator->() {
        std::cout << "first" << std::endl;
        return LockedPtr(this);
    }

private:
    T t;
    mutable Mutex m;
};

struct Foo {
    void a() {
        std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    Synchronized<Foo> foo;
    foo->a();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
first
Locking
second
a
Unlocking
```

My question is: Why is this code valid? Does this pattern have a name?

The -> operator is called twice, but it has only been written once.

Comment: The usage of operator-> for locking\unlocking is genius!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because that's what the standard says:

#### 13.5.6 Class member access [over.ref]

> 1) `operator->` shall be a non-static member function taking no
>   parameters. It implements class member access using `->
>   postfix-expression -> id-expression` **An expression `x->m` is interpreted
>   as `(x.operator->())->m` for a class object `x` of type `T` if
>   `T::operator->()` exists and if the operator is selected as the best
>   match function by the overload resolution mechanism (13.3).**

(emphasis mine)

In your case, `x` is `foo` and `m` is `a()`, Now, `Synchronized` overloads `operator->`, `foo->a()` is equivalent to:

```
(foo.operator->())->a();
```

`foo.operator->()` is your overload in class `Synchronized`, which returns a `LockedPtr`, and then that `LockedPtr` calls its own `operator->`.

Comment: Why doesn't the line p->m.unlock() also print "second"?

Comment: @gil_bz: p is a point at this line, and will therefor not invoke the -> operator

Comment: Doesn't the line p->m.lock() print the original "second"?

Comment: @gil_baz: no, it doesn't. The original "second" is printed when `LockedPtr::operator->` is called by the line `foo->a();`, after `Synchronized::operator->` has returned. The standard quote above says, in plain English, that when you use `->` in an expression what happens is that the implementation calls overloaded `operator->` and then keeps calling it on the result of that until eventually something returns a pointer. `p->ANYTHING` doesn't call `LockedPtr::operator->` or `Synchronized::operator->`, because `p` is neither a `LockedPtr` nor a `Synchronized`. It's a `Synchronized*`.

Comment: Similar explanation is here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access

_If a user-defined `operator->` is provided, the `operator->` is called again on the value that it returns, **recursively**, until an `operator->` is reached that returns a **plain pointer**. After that, built-in semantics are applied to that pointer._

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself this: how else could it possibly behave?

Remember, the point of overloading `operator->` at all is so that a smart pointer class can use the same syntax as a raw pointer.  That is, if you have:

```
struct S
{
    T m;
};
```

and you have a pointer `p` to `S`, then you access `S::m` via `p->m` regardless of whether `p` is an `S*` or some `pointer_class<S>` type.

There's also the difference between using `->` and invoking `operator->` directly:

```
pointer_class<S> pointerObj;
S* p = pointerObj.operator->();
```

Note that if using an overloaded `->` didn't automatically descend the extra level, what would `p->m` ever possibly mean?  How could the overload ever be used?